# GIF type animation for marker in google map api ANDROID

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-handler

I want to achieve a marker animation such as GIF animation. I got two images which should be blinking simultaneously. I found nothing which can acheive this in android. I am trying to do is , creating a handler which run every 1 second , and I am trying to set icon for marker. But it doesnt work. Please guide me in right direction.

my code as of now is as follows.

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();
  Boolean marker_color_bool = true;

//adding marker and sending the marker instance to marker_animation() method where handler is called.

MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .title(delivery_center_name)
                .snippet("This is the " + delivery_center_name + " location")
                .position(location)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red_marker));

        google_map.addMarker(marker);

        marker_animation(marker);
```

marker_animation() method

```
 private final int ONE_SECONDS = 1000;
public void marker_animation(final MarkerOptions marker ) {

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Log.e("running",""+marker_color_bool);

            if(marker_color_bool == true)
            {

                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.green_marker));
                marker_color_bool = false;
            }
            else
            {
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red_marker));
                marker_color_bool = true;
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, ONE_SECONDS);
        }
    }, ONE_SECONDS);
}
```

this approach doesnt work..Please help me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It would be better if people give a reason in comment as why the question was voted down. So that me as well as other people can understand and learn how to ask a question effectively.  Thanks..:-)

Comment: can you post your solution to this answer?

Comment: @PabloCegarra I am using Marker instead of marker options. Marker = new Marker(). and also it has setIcon which changes icon in animation handler from the above code.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Regis_AG yes, please find the above comment for my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please help me what I am doing wrong

You are modifying an object that is no longer being used. Once `addMarker()` is called, the `MarkerOptions` object has no further meaning, yet this is what you are modifying via your `postDelayed()` logic.

(BTW, you don't need a `Handler`, as `postDelayed()` is available on any `View`)

`addMarker()` returns a `Marker`. You will need to work with that `Marker` to affect your changes, via `setIcon()`.

Also, since your bitmaps are not changing, I suggest caching your two `BitmapDescriptor` objects, rather than re-creating them on every pass.

Comment: yup finally i solved it using marker instead of markeroptions, and also marker.seticon .

Comment: I want a loading indicator inside this marker image, and my marker image is a custom image, how can I do that?

Comment: @neena: If by "loading indicator", you mean something animated, that is not supported.

Comment: yes, i need animation saying its loading, if not supported, how can I do that?

Comment: @neena: Have your progress indicator be somewhere else, I guess.